# The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 0

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to open a .ipynb file in vscode and encounter this error:

[image]

This is strange because of many .ipynb files in the same folder I have, only this one when opened has this issue. Maybe because of tensorflow? Yesterday everything was fine, the whole folder is stored in an SSD drive with a SATA cable. This morning when after I unplugged the SSD drive from the PC and plugged it into the laptop, this error popped up. I have never seen this error before.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter extension, switching to previous release, opened it in the text editor and saw this:

[image]

This file is very important and I don't wanna to lose it. Could you show me a way to solve this?

Comment: You may want to have HxD or another binary viewer when inspecting binary files. It appears that you are trying to open a PNG based on the first few characters of the file signature.

Comment: This started to happen to me randomly - could only get around it by using this free hex editor tool https://freehexeditorneo.com/ -  try that or the vscode extension "Hex Editor"

Answer (score 0):

You can open this file in text editor (as the error suggests). There you'll see highlighted parts of code and several buttons around them: Accept incoming change, Compare changes and some others. You should press one of these buttons (according to what you'd like to do, for me it was "Accept incoming change") and the highlight from this part of code will be removed. When you remove all the highlights you right-click on this file tab and choose "Reopen editor with"->"Jupiter Notebook". Your code will be saved :)